# Why is Apollo GraphQL rendering nothing?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, graphql, apollo

As per https://www.apollographql.com/

I have a component:

```html
const OrganizationsList = () => (
  <Query
    query={gql`
      {searchOrganizations(count: 10, offset: 0)
        {
          id,
          legalBusinessName,
          shops {
            shopId,
            shopVersion,
            organizationId,
            sortIndex,
            alternativeName
          }
        }
      }
    `}
  >
    {({ loading, error, data }) => {
      if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>
      if (error) return <p>Error :(</p>
      console.log(data.searchOrganizations)

      return data.searchOrganizations.map((organization, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <p>{`${organization.id}: ${organization.legalBusinessName}`}</p>
        </div>
      ))
    }}
  </Query>
)

class ListOrganizationsPage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <OrganizationsList />
    )
  }
}
```

To my understanding, it should render data only when data is fetched, otherwise, `loading` should be rendered.

However, `loading` is rendered and nothing else.
In the console, data is logged and then this error pops up:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Query.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array
>   or some other invalid object.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't it cause you return an array instead of a of React element. Should be

```
return (<div>
  { 
    data.searchOrganizations.map((organization, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <p>{`${organization.id}: ${organization.legalBusinessName}`}</p>
        </div>))}
   </div>)
```

Comment: Yes! I was expecting it was something obvious. Thanks!